# SWF Decompiler in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, flash, decompiler

I'm looking for a module or a source code in Javascript/Node to decompile swf.

I tried to read a swf file and I get a buffer full of hexa.

So do you know a source or a module/plugin in JS/node to do that ? Or is this inexistant in this language ?

(I found some in PHP and Java but if one already exist in JS it would be cool !)

Thank's !